# logstash sincedb file not created with docker-compose

Tags: amazon-ec2, docker-compose, logstash

I have a logstash instance running with docker-compose on an AWS EC2 (AMI) instance. I have mounted a folder as volume to the container. I have logstash pipeline config to write the sincedb file in the mounted folder. The pipeline runs but it doesn't write anything for the sincedb file.

The same configuration works on my local machine, but not on EC2. I have checked that the user has rights to write in the folder by creating a file there (eg: vi test).

**Docker compose config:**

```
version: "2"
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.2.0
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
      - ./logstash/settings/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - ../data/:/usr/data/:rw
      - ./logstash/templates/:/usr/share/logstash/templates/
    container_name: logstash
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
    env_file:
      - ../env/.env.logstash
```

**Logstash input:**

```
input{
  s3 {
    access_key_id => "${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}"
    bucket => "xyz-bucket"
    secret_access_key => "${AWS_SECRET_KEY}"
    region => "eu-west-1"
    prefix => "logs/"
    type => "log"
    codec => "json"
    sincedb_path => "/usr/data/log-sincedb.file"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed this. Had to explicitly add user:root in the docker-compose service config.

```
version: "2"
services:
  logstash:
    image: docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:7.2.0
    user: root
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/pipeline/:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline/
      - ./logstash/settings/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
      - ../data/:/usr/data/:rw
      - ./logstash/templates/:/usr/share/logstash/templates/
    container_name: logstash
    ports:
      - 9600:9600
    env_file:
      - ../env/.env.logstash
```